# use quotation marks in regex, in quotation marks in C#

Tags: c#, regex, quotes

Note: all the quotation marks in this question are actually part of the code.

I'm learning regex, and i'm trying to scrape a site with music on it. I put the source of the site into a text file called 'ytcmusic.txt'. Here's a sample of the html:

```
<li><a href="angelpool%20-%20know.mp3"> angelpool - know.mp3</a></li>
<li><a href="angelpool%20-%20sellout.mp3"> angelpool - sellout.mp3</a></li>
<li><a href="angelpool%20-%20time.mp3"> angelpool - time.mp3</a></li>
<li><a href="bella%20-%20gibsons.mp3"> bella - gibsons.mp3</a></li>
```

i'll use the first line as an example, i'm trying to scrape only the "angelpool%20-%20know.mp3" and to do that here's the regex i used: ".*.mp3"    ------ when I put it into C#, I have to surround it in quotation marks, which ruins the quotation marks in the regex. heres the code (it doesn't compile, if you remove one set of quotation marks around the regex, it does but obviously doesnt return the correct part of the source):

```
var sr = new StreamReader("ytcmusic.txt");
        string str = sr.ReadToEnd();
        var match = Regex.Match(str, @".*.mp3");
```

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will do

```
"[^"]*"
```

Note that I'm keeping you to your sample input and assuming the titles are the only thing quoted. If that's not the case you have to put more context into the regex.

If you want to capture without the quotes you can introduce parenthesis like so

```
"([^"]*)"
```

In C# this becomes

```
StringCollection resultList = new StringCollection();
Regex regexObj = new Regex("\"([^\"]*)\"");
Match matchResult = regexObj.Match(subjectString);
while (matchResult.Success) {
    resultList.Add(matchResult.Groups[1].Value);
    matchResult = matchResult.NextMatch();
}
```

Comment: sorry, i'm a bit of a noob, how would i add that into my code? i've tried a few different ways with errors. thanks

Comment: If you know each file will be on 1 line, it would be better to read & match line by line. Also, * is greedy, or maximal, so will match as much as it can to satisfy the preceding expression, eg the first quote till the last quote. Add a ? after the * to make it none-greedy and match as little as possible.

Comment: @SimonHalsey I hear you but since a negated character class is used it will not be greedy and will result in no backtracking at all. It's a common technique and an alternative to lazy matching which can involve (lots) of backtracking.

Comment: Wasn't aware that negated classes were non-greedy. Handy to know.

Comment: sorry it took me a bit to choose this as a right answer, i was a bit busy. just tried it out and it works great! thanks!

Comment: Thank you, this is the only answer that works for me