# Remove newlines inside quotation marks with Regex in C#

Tags: c#, regex

I need to remove some unwanted newlines inside quotation marks in a csv file.

The input file looks like the example below:

```
0433000007880;2;text SOME TEXT;9;TOT 
0556000007880;5;SOME TEXT;6;"ECG


             22.54 "
0556000007880;6;some other text;2;00535
```

Desired output:

```
0433000007880;2;text SOME TEXT;9;TOT 
0556000007880;5;SOME TEXT;6;"ECG 22.54 "
0556000007880;6;some other text;2;00535
```

Now, the quotation marks can be identified by `"[^"]*"`, as mentioned in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11217170/use-quotation-marks-in-regex-in-quotation-marks-in-c-sharp). What I'm missing is how to replace the new lines INSIDE the regex match.

Comment: Can't there be literal double quotes inside the CSV? Like `12;"text ""in quotes"" and more";456`?

Comment: As @WiktorStribiżew says things like I need a 12" ruler....

Comment: In your example you not only delete the newlines, but also the quotation marks ... is that correct?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew this is the input I was given. Some records have are split into multiple lines due to the quotes.

Comment: @Fildor you are right, but this is not my main concern. I modified the question though. Good point, thanks

Answer (score -1):

You can combine the regex approach with `Trim()` method to get the results.
First, capture the empty lines with the `"[^"]*` regex, then replace the spaces with another regex and call `Trim()` on the result:

```
string Sanitize(string line)
{
    if(!Regex.IsMatch(line, @"""[^""]*"))
        return line;

    string pattern = @"\s+|"""; // <-- match multiple spaces or " character
    Regex regex = new Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.Multiline);
    string replacement = @" ";
    // replace matched strings with a single space
    var replaced = regex.Replace(line, replacement);
    // since " at the beginning and end of the string 
    // are replaced by spaces, trim those spaces before returning
    return replaced.Trim();
}
```